# Bash script infinite loop while reading file

Tags: bash, infinite-loop, readfile

I am writing a simple bash script to read filenames from a text file and check if they exist in the directory. While this works fine, after all the files are parsed, I am getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
        echo "No input file to parse given. Give me an input file and make sure the corresponding .gz files are in the folder."
else
        file=$1
        echo "Loaded $file."
        while read -r line
        currentfile="$line.gz"
        do
                if [ -f $currentfile ]; then
                        echo "The file '$currentfile' exists."
                else
                        echo "The file '$currentfile' does not exist."
                fi
        done < "$file"
fi
```

And this is the looping output after all the files are listed:

```
The file '.gz' does not exist.
The file '.gz' does not exist.
The file '.gz' does not exist.
The file '.gz' does not exist.
The file '.gz' does not exist.
The file '.gz' does not exist.
etc.
```

I know the solution must be very simple, but it's been bugging me for most of the morning! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
    currentfile="$line.gz"
```

doesn't belong between the `read` and `do`, does it? It makes the condition always true.

Move it after the `do`.

Comment: Much obliged, kind sir!